# Groupby and get value offset by one year in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, pandas-groupby

My goal today is to follow each ID that belongs to `Category==1` in a given date, one year later. So I have a dataframe like this:

```
Period      ID    Amount   Category
20130101    1       100       1
20130101    2       150       1
20130101    3       100       1
20130201    1       90        1
20130201    2       140       1
20130201    3       95        1
20130201    5       250       0
   .        .       .
20140101    1       40        1
20140101    2       70        1
20140101    5       160       0
20140201    1       35        1
20140201    2       65        1
20140201    5       150       0
```

For example, in `20130201` I have 2 ID's that belong to `Category` 1: 1,2,3, but just 2 of them are present in `20140201`: 1,2. So I need to get the value of `Amount`, only for those ID's, one year later, like this:

```
Period      ID    Amount   Category    Amount_t1
20130101    1       100       1           40
20130101    2       150       1           70
20130101    3       100       1           nan
20130201    1       90        1           35
20130201    2       140       1           65
20130201    3       95        1           nan
20130201    5       250       0           nan
   .        .       .
20140101    1       40        1           nan
20140101    2       70        1           nan
20140101    5       160       0           nan
20140201    1       35        1           nan 
20140201    2       65        1           nan
20140201    5       150       0           nan
```

So, if the ID doesn't appear next year or belong to `Category` 0, I'll get a `nan`. My first approach was to get the list of unique ID's on each `Period` and then trying to map that to the next year, using some sort of combination of `groupby()` and `isin()` like this:

```
aux = df[df.Category==1].groupby('Period').ID.unique()
aux.index = aux.index + pd.DateOffset(years=1)
```

But I didn't know how to keep going. I'm thinking some kind of `groupby('ID')` might be more efficient too. If it were a simple `shift()` that would be easy, but I'm not sure about how to get the value offset by a year by group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create lagged features with an exact merge after you manually lag one of the join keys.

```
import pandas as pd

# Datetime so we can do calendar year subtraction
df['Period'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Period, format='%Y%m%d')

# Create one with the lagged features. Here I'll split the steps out.
df2 = df.copy()
df2['Period'] = df2.Period-pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)  # 1 year lag
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'Amount': 'Amount_t1'})

# Keep only values you want to merge
df2 = df2[df2.Category.eq(1)]

# Bring lagged features
df.merge(df2, on=['Period', 'ID', 'Category'], how='left')
```

---

```
       Period  ID  Amount  Category  Amount_t1
0  2013-01-01   1     100         1       40.0
1  2013-01-01   2     150         1       70.0
2  2013-01-01   3     100         1        NaN
3  2013-02-01   1      90         1       35.0
4  2013-02-01   2     140         1       65.0
5  2013-02-01   3      95         1        NaN
6  2013-02-01   5     250         0        NaN
7  2014-01-01   1      40         1        NaN
8  2014-01-01   2      70         1        NaN
9  2014-01-01   5     160         0        NaN
10 2014-02-01   1      35         1        NaN
11 2014-02-01   2      65         1        NaN
12 2014-02-01   5     150         0        NaN
```